# Что означает %s и % в аргументах функции в Django?

Tags: python, django

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

Comment: %s означает что на место этого знака нужно вставить строку, последующая % - та строка которая должна быть вместо %s

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей

Comment: django тут ни при чём, если что

Comment: Да, это вича самого Pythona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%s означает что на место этого знака нужно вставить строку, последующая % - та строка которая должна быть вместо %s

Comment: формат строки.устаревшее но рабочее

Answer (score 2):

```
def detail(request, question_id):
return HttpResponse(f"You're looking at question {question_id}.")
```

Да, это такой синтаксис Python.
Приятнее и быстрее будет работать с f-строками.
И читабельнее.